# App to record audio and add tags/chapter marks/timestamps at the same time?

Tags: android, audio-recording, voice-recording

I'm looking for a simple voice recorder that records the external mic, but with one added functionality: I need a (preferably big) button on screen that I can tap while recording, so that when I finish recording, I already have timestamps of important parts of the conversation. It seems there was such an app 10 years ago, but the links are of course long-dead: https://www.addictivetips.com/android/recorder-with-tags-android/